# I need a regular expression to find a string that's not commented out

Tags: javascript, regex

my regular expression is currently:

```
includes.push\("([^\"\"]*\.js)"\)
```

but it matches all of the following lines

```
/*includes.push("javascriptfile.js")*/
/*
includes.push("javascriptfile.js")
*/
includes.push("javascriptfile.js");
includes.push("javascriptfile.js")
```

And I don't want it to match the lines within comments.

Any regex experts out there got any ideas?

Thanks :o)

**Edit** I have tested a regex slightly adapted from madgnome. this picks up multiline ones in my test, can you see any problems with it?

```
includes\.push("([^\"\"]*\.js)")(?!\n**/)
```

new test is:

```
/*includes.push("javascriptfile.js")*/
/*
includes.push("javascriptfile.js")
*/
includes.push("javascriptfile.js");
includes.push("javascriptfile.js");
/*includes.push("javascriptfile.js")*/
/*
includes.push("javascriptfile.js")
*/
```

This includes comments underneath the initial includes strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your language, you could use negative lookbehind/lookahead

```
(?<!/\*)includes\.push\("([^\"\"]*\.js)"\)(?!\*/)
```

- `(?<!/\*)` asserts that it is impossible to match the regex `/\*` before current position
- `(?!\*/)` asserts that it is impossible to match the regex `\*/` after current position

This regex won't work for multiline comments like your second example, you should trim before use.

**Edit:** You are using javascript, and negative lookbehind doesn't work in javascript, you could use only the negative lookahead like that :

```
includes\.push\("([^\"\"]*\.js)"\)(?![\r\n\s]*\*/)
```

*(This regex works for multiline comments like your second example but won't with malformed comments : `*/` without `/*`)*

Comment: Thanks, it's the multiline one which is really got me stumped! unfortunately this is the one which raised the issue in the first place and i can't strip out comments beforehand.

Comment: Dave, can you replace comments with a unique token, then do the work, then replace the unique token with the original comment again?

Comment: Thanks, it didn't seem to pick up the multiline ones in my test but this one seems to, can you see any problems with it? `includes\.push\("([^\"\"]*\.js)"\)(?!\n*\*/)`

Comment: Try this `includes\.push\("[^"]*\.js"\)(?![\r\n]*\*/)`

Comment: Cracked it...brilliant, thanks for your help `includes\.push\("([^\"\"]*\.js)"\)(?![\r\n\s]*\*/)` it is

Answer (score 0):

You could just match either comments (multi- or single line), or a string literal and inspect the entire match-array:

```
var text = 
    "// \"foo\" \n" +
    "var s = \"no /* comment */ in here \"; \n" +
    "/*includes.push(\"javascriptfileA.js\")*/\n" +
    "/*\n" +
    "includes.push(\"javascriptfileB.js\")\n" +
    "*/\n" +
    "includes.push(\"javascriptfileC.js\");\n" +
    "includes.push(\"javascriptfileD.js\")\n";

print("--------------------------------------\ntext:\n");

var hits = text.match(/\/\/[^\r\n]*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"/g);

print(text);

print("--------------------------------------\nhits:\n");

for(i in hits) {
  var hit = hits[i]; 
  if(hit.indexOf("\"") == 0) {
    print(hit);
  }
}
```

produces:

```
--------------------------------------
text:

// "foo" 
var s = "no /* comment */ in here "; 
/*includes.push("javascriptfileA.js")*/
/*
includes.push("javascriptfileB.js")
*/
includes.push("javascriptfileC.js");
includes.push("javascriptfileD.js")

--------------------------------------
hits:

"no /* comment */ in here "
"javascriptfileC.js"
"javascriptfileD.js"
```

A short explanation of the regex:

```
//[^\r\n]*         # match a single line comment
|                  # OR
/\*[\s\S]*?\*/     # match a multi-line comment
|                  # OR
"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"  # match a string literal
```

Tested online on [IDEone](http://ideone.com/P5OIH).